# What is the purpose of __str__ method for a class?

Tags: python, string, methods

Does anyone know an extremely simple example showing the importance and use of the `__str__` method in Python??

Comment: what programming language ?

Comment: @karthikr I think this is Python.

Comment: `f = 1.234; print f`. The `__str__` protocol makes this possible to work with an arbitrary object, but the usefulness should be immediately evident with converting a number to its *text representation*. Many languages support a similar construct (e.g. toString/ToString/to_s).

Comment: woah! my bad. Yeah, Python.

Answer (score 3):

In Python that will be the return value by the `str()` function when passing an instance of your class as the first argument. For example:

```
class Class:
    def __str__(self):
        return "You've converted Class to string."

c = Class()
print str(c)
```

If you do not define that method the `str()` function will return something like:

> <Class instance at 0xf9e0a60ec5872050>

Hope it helps :-)